# Python: how to write to fd 3?

Tags: python, c, stdout, file-descriptor, fdopen

in C, I can write to file descriptor 3 like this:

```
$ cat write.c 
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    write(3, "written in fd 3\n", 16);
}
```

Then I can call the program and redirect fd 3 to fd 1 (stdin) like this:

```
$ ./write 3>&1
written in fd 3
```

How can I do that in python?
I checked `os.open()` but it creates a file descriptor out of a file in the filesystem (apparently I can't select which file descriptor to allocate) and `os.fdopen()` creates a file object out of a file descriptor (created with `os.open()`). So, how can I choose the file descriptor number.

I tried:

```
with os.fdopen(3, 'w+') as fdfile:
```

but it gives me:

```
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

EDIT:
This is my python program:

```
$ cat fd.py
import os

with os.fdopen(3, 'w+') as fdfile:
    fdfile.write("written to fd 3\n")
    fdfile.close()
```

And this is the result when I run it:

```
$ python fd.py 3>&1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fd.py", line 3, in <module>
    with os.fdopen(3, 'w+') as fdfile:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 1023, in fdopen
    return io.open(fd, *args, **kwargs)
io.UnsupportedOperation: File or stream is not seekable.
```

Comment: notice that fd 3 is just stderr

Comment: @user12986714 stderr is FD 2

Comment: Did you use `3>&1` when running the python script, like you did when running the C program?

Comment: @Barmar thank you. I suppose then fd 1 should be stdout?

Comment: @user12986714 Yes. stdin = 0, stdout = 1, stderr = 2

Comment: Your error message shows you're trying to access file descriptor 4, not 3.

Comment: @Barmar, I commented in your reply

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, I had pasted the wrong part of the result, sorry. I fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `"w+"` to `"w"` in the call to `os.fdopen`.  That's what's causing the "not seekable" error.  The `+` tells it to open it for both reading and writing, which won't work.

Comment: Have you ever noticed that almost all `open()` calls in code posted on SO have `w+` modes?

Comment: @Barmar Hm, yeah I guess it does some up a lot.  There must be some bad example out there that people are getting it from.

Comment: btw, why can't I read from a file descriptor? Why can't I open it with w+, write to it and then read from it?

Comment: also, tutorialspint has an example with "w+", but it is to do an os.fdopen() using in fd already opened by os.open(), so it works fine in that case (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_fdopen.htm)

Comment: @Adriano_Pinaffo FD 1 is `stdout`, which you can only write to, not read.

Comment: @Barmar, I meant fd3, not 1.

Comment: But FD 3 is dup'ed from FD 1, so it has the same restrictions. @Adriano_Pinaffo

Comment: Also, they're connected to a tty, which isn't seekable. If you'd redirected FD 1 to a file before running this, you wouldn't get that error.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work. But just like when running the C program, you have to redirect FD 3 first.

```
python write.py 3>&1
```

Comment: I did that, but the problem is os.fdopen() which can't open the file descriptor 3. I believe os.fdopen() can only assign a file object after it has been open with os.open(), no? I edited my question

Comment: @TomKarzes, how do I open it without using a file in the filesystem or tempfile.mkstemp()?

Comment: you are rigth. It worked, thanks. If you want to reply it I mark as answered

Comment: For me it works with python 2, but python 3 raises `not seekable`.

Comment: @Friedrich See the other answer: Get rid of the `+` in the mode.. I don't know why so many programmers use that when it's not needed.